# Extending .one for link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, submenu

At the moment I have a link which has a .one event:

```
$("li.deeper.parent").one("click",false);
```

After the first click it does not follow the link, the second time it does. After the first click a submenu opens too (a whole diffent part code - not for now).

What I'd like is that if you click on the link, it performs the same action as it does now. But if you click outside of the link anywhere else on the page, I want to close the submenu (I have that already) but also "reset" the link. So if you click on the link, submenu opens. Click anywhere else on the page: submenu closes. What happens now is that when you click again on the link, it follows the link. What I want is that the .one event is called again. I'm not quite good in explaining myself, sorry :)

Thanks for your time, I hope anyone has a solution

Comment: When using the .one() method, the handler is unbound after its first invocation. In other words, it will work once before the handler is removed. Use `.on()` or `.click()` instead.

Comment: @Dom Yeah but after the first click on the link it should follow the link, so only the first time it should return false. But if I click on something else I want to "reset" the .one element.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: Apparently I can't get it to work in a jsfiddle, but it isn't much more than in my OP. I appreciate the help, I'm sorry I don't know more to explain.

Comment: Maybe better info is that I used this jsfiddle and modified it for my use but when I use that I need to click three (!) times on the link before it follows the link? edit: forgot the link... http://jsfiddle.net/RzzCu/11/

Comment: @Dom, thanks for your help but I solved it in the mean time I think!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using one, do the following:

```
var oneVar=false;
$("li.deeper.parent").on("click",function(){
    if(!oneVar){
        oneVar=true;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //the code you want to happen after the second click
    }
});
```

also when you're closing the submenu on click of anywhere else on the page at the beginning of the code set the oneVar to false again like this `oneVar=false;`

Comment: I think I came up with a solution similar to this, but instead of a variable I used a class (since that's already used for showing the submenu). Thanks, since I would probably have came up with my solution after reading yours :)